# Types of joins and expected output

Tags: sql, join, match, multiple-records

I have a table that has wholesale data and retail data.
the data is structured as

| Channel | Serial# | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WS-Build | 12345 | 1/1/2019 |
| WS-Dealer | 34567 | 1/5/2021 |
| Retail | 12345 | 1/1/2020 |
| Retail | 34567 | 3/5/2021 |

I would like the output to match on serial#

Each serial # will appear twice in the table. I am trying to get a count of # of units sold via builder or dealer.

| Serial# | Channel | WholesaleDate | Retail Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | WS-Build | 1/1/2019 | 1/1/2020 |
| 34567 | WS-Dealer | 1/5/2021 | 3/5/2021 |

How can i achieve that by joining on the same table?

Comment: why is the second serial number 34569 different from the first 34567?

Comment: Fixed it , good catch

Answer (score 0):

Try join by serial and channel

```
select t1.serial#, t2.WholesaleDate, t2."Retail Date", (*) from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.serial# = t2.serial# and t1.channel = t2.channel
group by t1.serial#, , t2.WholesaleDate, t2."Retail Date";
```

Comment: your query will not work on this example because if you see the expected output it's not the same as the original table there is one more column that you need

Comment: how can a do a count if serial matches?

Comment: What kind of conditions should you have to match? Serial number and channel? Or something else?

Comment: The expected output  is created using the same table 1. However in output i would like to see wholesale date and the matching retail date for the same serial#.

Comment: @SwaD The condition it needs to match is first find the 2 records of mathcing serial #'s then output serial# A wholesaled on date X and retailed on date Y . What I am trying to achieve is X units were shipped in wholesale-builder in year (whatever) that sold Vs Y units shipped in wholesale-dealer that sold in year (whatever)

Comment: Finally got this working thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the retail is after the sale you can do

but i don't get where the counts come in

```
SELECT
 t1."Serial#",t1."Channel", t1."Date" as WholesaleDate, t2."Date" as "Retail Date"
FROM tab1 t1 JOIN tab1 t2 ON t1."Serial#" = t2."Serial#" AND t1."Date" < t2."Date"
```

| Serial# | Channel | wholesaledate | Retail Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | WS-Build | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 34567 | WS-Dealer | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 2021-05-03 00:00:00 |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/E49N95aN)